# why .property('someProperty'); used in computed properties in ember.js

Tags: javascript, frameworks, ember.js

I am very new to Ember.js and read its documentation and also following given starting example. They use `property` method in computed properties and pass a model property (some time with @each). I don't know why they use it. Here duration is made available using `this.get('model.duration')` than why `.property('model.duration')`

```
App.SongController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  duration: function() {
    var duration = this.get('model.duration'),
         minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60),
         seconds = duration % 60;
    return [minutes, seconds].join(':');
  }.property('model.duration')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Computed Property `.property()` is cached by default. ie., the value is not computed everytime when you call the property.

To compute the value of the computed property again when any of its dependent key changes, we need to specify its dependencies...

However we can turn off the cacheable option by using `.property().volatile()`

Refer [Ember API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_property)

Comment: Ok, its mean telling Ember.js to watch the following properties (in `.property('firstName','lastName')`) and recompute desired property (`fullName`) whenever  change occur in `fristName` or `lastName`. Thanks for words and reference link

Comment: Yeah and the recompute is done only when you get the property using Ember.get

Comment: one more thing when we should use `@each.someProperty` or `todos.@each.isCompleted` instead of just `isCompleted`. I read it in Todos example from ember.js (it is done in `ArrayController` not in `ObjectController`)

Comment: When your content is an array, ArrayController plays the role... Assume you have an array of objects as [{task: 'xxx',isCompleted: false},{task:'yyy', isCompleted: false},{task:'zzz', isCompleted: true}] whose 'isCompleted' property changes, Now if you need a property with array  of completed tasks, you can have it as a computed property with its dependent keys as the content array... This will update your property when any of the array content Changes... http://jsbin.com/ocucax/1/edit